# Why are my bones moving like this?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, vertex-groups

I just connected bones in an armature and I'm having this problem where the mesh doesn't move with the bones as it should.

Not moved:

[image]

Moved:

[image]

As you can see, the bone is going much farther but the actual finger is moving very slowly and stops at a certain point. What could this be?

Also, I have another issue to where when I move the parent of that bone, the whole finger screws up. It just turns into a mess:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46315/how-do-rigs-relate-to-weights/46322#46322

Comment: Maybe useful tip: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94166/how-can-my-animation-animate-if-there-is-no-vertex-weights/94168#94168