# Weight painting two unconnected meshes

Tags: weight-painting

[.blend file](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=48539)

I have two different meshes, one for the leg and one for the foot. They are joined but unconnected. They are both connected with a shin bone.

However, if I rotate that bone then the two meshes are not "synchronized" even though both meshes are red.

[image]

Can somebody help me to localize the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot is showing the weights relative to the shin bone only. Every vertex is affected by all weights assigned relative to all others bones (probably foot, in example): if you want all the vertices of the bottom ring of the leg to move exactly as the upper ring of the foot, all thoose vertices must be weighted in the exact same way relatively to all the bones in which you have some weight.

See this answer for more infos:

[How can my animation animate if there is no vertex weights?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94166/how-can-my-animation-animate-if-there-is-no-vertex-weights/94168#94168)

Comment: You were right, the bone "thigh" influenced the mesh at lower part of the shin, thats why this happened. Thank you!