Weird stretch while trying to rig/animate
As you can see as I move it, it pulls just a section and gives way. All is applied and weight is all blue. I appreciate any help, thanks.


Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94166/how-can-my-animation-animate-if-there-is-no-vertex-weights?rq=1
